# element v/s $(' ') in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

After including jQuery.js

`$('#iPut').css('width', '150px');` works where as 
`element('#id').css('width', '150px');` does not work. What is the principal difference b/w the two?

Comment: Provide some more context/code.

Comment: will provide fiddle, in like 2 mins. working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element` (assuming we're talking Angular directives) is a jQuery object, like the one that would have been returned by `$('#iPut')`. It's not a function, like `$`, that you can call and pass a selector to.

So if you want to set the width of `element`, use it like this:

```
element.css('width', '150px');
```

Comment: so how do you provide '#id' to it?

Comment: @SangramSingh no it wouldn't, just like it wouldn't in 'real' jQuery either

Comment: so how do you provide '#id' to it?

Comment: @SangramSingh since you're already loading `jQuery`, just use `$` like you would normally. I'm assuming that you want to change the width of some element in the DOM identified by `#id`, which has nothing to do with `element`?

Comment: true. It just felt non-angulary. so was fearing unexpected trouble later.

Comment: @SangramSingh if `#id` is related to `element` somehow, you can still use stuff like `element.find()` or `element.siblings()`.